# Add an extra react element into FullCalendar header

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using FullCalendar for react application.

```
           <FullCalendar
                plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                events={calendarEvents}
                initialView="timeGridDay"
                selectable={true}
                dateClick={handleDateClick}
                select={handleSelectClick}
                headerToolbar={{
                    left: "prev,next today",
                    center: "title",
                    right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
                }}
                initialDate={initialDate ?? new Date()}
                nowIndicator={true}
                datesSet={(dateInfo: DatesSetArg) => handleChangeDatesSet && handleChangeDatesSet(dateInfo)}
                dayMaxEventRows={4}
                eventClick={(eventInfo: EventClickArg) => handleEventClick && handleEventClick(eventInfo)}
                eventContent={renderEventContent}
                
            />
```

Now, I want to add a `search input field` in the right header. How can I achieve it.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do that via the fullCalendar API unfortunately. The most it allows you to do is create [custom buttons](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons). Perhaps you can support a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to allow arbitrary custom HTML elements to be added to the header. So for now you'd have to resort to manipulating the DOM directly to inject the content where you need it within fullCalendar's rendered HTML.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution until now?